# A route with parameters in Angular outputs 404

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Project on Angular 13.

Route description

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'my-path/:my-param',
        component: MyComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and here is the transition to it

```
this.router.navigate(['my-path'], { queryParams: { my-param: 'value' } });
```

As a result, I am thrown out on page 404.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try this: `this.router.navigate(['my-path', 'value']);`. `queryParams` isn't applicable based on the code you have in the post.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either.
Why can't I use queryParams.  What's wrong with me?

Comment: So where does it actually navigate to? Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

you may check your index.html file if there is a base tag added to the head part.

```
<base href="/">
```